# C++ WinAPI[GDI]. Custom gui correct redraw

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating custom gui, using WinAPI and GDI. I have some problems, with redrawing it. If i will drag window, it redraw great, but if i drag window beyond the screen it not redraw. Look at screenshots below:

[Normal window moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyZtp.png)

[Move window beyond the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2HsF.png)

[Move back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w9pq.png)

ToxicInjector.cpp:

```
#include "ToxicInjector.h"

...

// Method register native window object
bool ToxicInject::Application::RegisterNativeWindow()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc{ sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    ...
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    ...
}

// Window message procedure
LRESULT ToxicInject::Application::WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // Executes when window creates
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            this->CreateNativeControls();
            ...
        }
        break;

        ...

        // Need for draw custom controls
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            static LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pdis = reinterpret_cast<LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT>(lParam);
            switch (pdis->CtlID)
            {
                case UPDATE_BUTTON:
                {
                    if (pdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
                        this->isMouseOnUpdateBtn = true;
                    else
                        this->isMouseOnUpdateBtn = false;

                    this->DrawUpdateButton(pdis->hDC);
                }
                break;

                case INJECT_BUTTON:
                {
                    if (pdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
                        this->isMouseOnInjectBtn = true;
                    else
                        this->isMouseOnInjectBtn = false;
                    this->DrawInjectButton(pdis->hDC);
                }
                break;

                case BROWSE_BUTTON:
                {
                    if (pdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
                        this->isMouseOnBrowseBtn = true;
                    else
                        this->isMouseOnBrowseBtn = false;

                    this->DrawBrowseButton(pdis->hDC);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        ...

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

...

// Method creates all native-window controls
void ToxicInject::Application::CreateNativeControls()
{
    ...

    this->hUpdate_Button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_VISIBLE| WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 224, 50, 212, 26, this->hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(this->UPDATE_BUTTON), 0, 0);
    this->hInject_Button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_VISIBLE| WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 224, 76 + 15, 212, 26, this->hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(this->INJECT_BUTTON), 0, 0);
    this->hBrowse_Button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_VISIBLE| WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 224, 91 + 26 + 15, 212, 26, this->hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(this->BROWSE_BUTTON), 0, 0);
}

...

// Method draw update button
void ToxicInject::Application::DrawUpdateButton(HDC hDC)
{
    ...

    if (this->isMouseOnUpdateBtn)
    {
        bg = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(44, 97, 46));

        /*DRAW BACKGROUND*/
        FillRect(hDC, &rc, bg);

        /*DRAW BOTTOM LINE*/
        SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
        MoveToEx(hDC, 0, 26, 0);
        LineTo(hDC, 212, 26);

        /*DRAW TEXT*/
        SetBkColor(hDC, RGB(44, 97, 46));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SelectObject(hDC, hTahoma_Regular);

        TextOut(hDC, 83, 3, L"Update", 7);

        /*FREE GDI MEMORY*/
        DeleteObject(bg);
        DeleteObject(hTahoma_Regular);
        DeleteObject(hPen);
    }
    else
    {
        bg = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(67, 156, 70));

        /*DRAW BACKGROUND*/
        FillRect(hDC, &rc, bg);

        /*DRAW BOTTOM LINE*/
        SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
        MoveToEx(hDC, 0, 26, 0);
        LineTo(hDC, 212, 26);

        /*DRAW TEXT*/
        SetBkColor(hDC, RGB(67, 156, 70));
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SelectObject(hDC, hTahoma_Regular);

        TextOut(hDC, 83, 2, L"Update", 7);

        /*FREE GDI MEMORY*/
        DeleteObject(bg);
        DeleteObject(hTahoma_Regular);
        DeleteObject(hPen);
    }
}

...
```

Sorry for my english =). How to fix that issue?

Comment: You should post your current working code or relevant code parts, so that others can suggest some solutions.

Comment: Yep, i update post.

Comment: What do you mean by "dragging the window beyond the screen" ?

Comment: Check 2nd and 3rd screenshots

Comment: Can you show the `CreateNativeControls` method?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's usually best to leave out all layers of abstraction (i.e. the C++ code) and only show the bare minimum. It's also not required to have repetitive code: If it fails for 3 button controls, it surely also fails for a single button control, so simply keep a single button in your MCVE.

Comment: UPD. Full code is here.

Comment: An MCVE is required to be *minimal*. There's no need to show the button handlers, or a lot of other, unrelated code. The C++ abstraction certainly doesn't help see through the code to identify the issue. Please provide a [mcve] (make sure to read the link thoroughly).

Comment: Now its good?; I think its perfect.

Comment: This is still neither complete nor minimal. We don't need to see code for 3 buttons, when a single button exhibits the undesired behavior. Neither is it relevant, that fonts are created or text is rendered. You can simply fill a solid rectangle, and use a system brush for that (call [GetStockObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject) to get one).

Comment: LOL! Minimal isn't 1000 lines of code. Just create an empty window with **one** button and fill its background. No need to draw lines etc...

Comment: Ok... now it minimal and returns main idea. Maybe you will help or wrote your ideas about this issue?

Comment: Nop. Your code **should** run as **is** **and** reproduce the issue! Yours doesn't run.

Comment: Ok give me 10min, i implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed it!.

```
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pdis = reinterpret_cast<LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT>(lParam);
            switch (pdis->CtlID)
            ...
        }
```

Pointer to `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` should be non-static!. It's logic error, my mistake.
Works perfectly =).

Answer (score -2):

You can force a repaint in answer to a WM_MOVE

```
case WM_MOVE:
    this->OnWindow_Paint();
    break;
```

Comment: Additionally you might want to set CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW in the window class style.

Comment: Proposing an answer, without diagnosing the issue or explaining, why it works, usually doesn't. Applying a solution without understand what it does or why it's necessary leads to what is called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Besides, the `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` [window class styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-class-styles) won't fix the issue. They pertain to behavior, when the *size of the client area changes*.

Comment: The *correct* way to trigger a redraw of a window is to use `InvalidateRect()` and let the system generate a new `WM_PAINT` message when it is ready to do so.

Comment: Nope, it's not working... I know i need trigger WM_PAINT by some api's like InvalidateRect or UpdateWindow... but when?

Comment: I know this, but why custom buttons not redraws, when i move window beyond the screen(screenshot2 and screenshot3 illustrate this)?